# WebStorm autocomplete not working for Angular @Input() defined in abstract class

Tags: angular, webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2017.2 for an Angular v4.3 project.

**The WebStorm autocomplete suggestions for adding directives to tags on Angular HTML templates does not offer suggestions for @Input() properties defined on abstract classes from which the template's component has been extended.**

https://plnkr.co/edit/OJEoafoPZpz8gaxEbTBb?p=preview

**fruit.component.ts (the abstract base class).**

```
import {Input} from '@angular/core';

export abstract class FruitComponent {
  @Input() protected ColourParent: string;
}
```

**item-of-fruit.component.ts (the derived child class).**

```
import {FruitComponent} from './fruit.component';
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-item-of-fruit',
  template: `<input placeholder="{{ColourChild}} / {{ColourParent}}"/>`
})
export class ItemOfFruitComponent extends FruitComponent {
  @Input() ColourChild: string;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<app-item-of-fruit [ColourChild]="'child-blue'" [ColourParent]="'parent-red'"></app-item-of-fruit>`
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

**Autocomplete does not offer the suggestion of [ColourParent] from the base class.**

[image: WebStorm autocomplete]

I would expect to see the autocomplete offer suggestions for both [ColourChild] and [ColourParent].

Is this a bug in WebStorm or am I doing something wrong?

Rel. Issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28178